# Mobile Safari on iPhone/iPod CSS hack

Tags: css, mobile-safari

Does anyone know a good modern CSS hack to target only mobile safari on iPhone and iPod Touch?

I keep seeing `@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px)`, but that's from 3 years ago and matches Nexus S among others now.

(This is to fix a subtle layout issue. I realise browser sniffing is evil etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://cssuseragent.org and welcome to the Dark Side.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bite the bullet and use this as it won't be the last time I need a CSS hack here.

Comment: +1 for posting a modernizr like solution for user agent hacks, that will (probably) be updated/maintained, and not fail from one day to another...as all other probably could/will.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)`

Comment: targets also my Nexus 4 with Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You could ask for `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2` as well. I don't believe there are browsers that report any higher than 2 at the moment (though some report lower, so use min-ratio) - however, this excludes the iPhone 3GS and non-retina iPod Touch devices. For those, you'd have to do some user-agent sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

only way to target specific devices on the web is to check user agent strings. All apple devices have their name in the user agent string. e.g. iphone will have "iphone" and ipod will have "ipod". Use this to dynamically apply or load css.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to target Safari on mobiles, just add a media query to this hack:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    _::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .safari_only {
        padding: 10px; //or any property you need
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add the **.safari_only** class to the element you want to target, example:

```
<div class='safari_only'> This div will have a padding:10px in a mobile with Safari  </div>
```

One detail: this is gonna affect also the Safari browser in Android devices but... anyway who use Safari in an Android device :)